# How do I set an environment variable needed by an extension running remotely using remote-ssh?

Tags: ssh, remote-server

We are using the remote-ssh extension to run VS Code locally on MacOS and remotely connecting to our code repo on Linux. This part works fine. But now I'm installing a custom extension (that we developed) that requires the JAVA_HOME environment variable to be set on the remote Linux host where the extension runs. I've tried a number of things, but I can't find the right way to set this environment variable in this remote-ssh flow.

I understand the VS Code Server is being run on the remote machine to enable the remote-ssh flow. Is there a way to set my required environment variable on the VS Code Server instance so that my extension sees it?

Answer (score 0):

The [direnv](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkhl.direnv) extension will do that, but you'll have to have [direnv](https://direnv.net) installed on the remote and have `.envrc` like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=...
```